# Compare similarity of images

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to automatically decide wether two figures are similar or not. You can find three examples here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/09Zqf.png

The first image is different from the second and third image, but the second and third are the same (not identical, if you look closely, there are some small differences)

My code (most of it is from the feature homography example in the OpenCV documentation) reads two different images, computes their keypoints and descriptors (using SIFT, but I have also tried SURF and ORB), matches them using the FlannBasedMatcher and computes the homography matrix. From the optional status vector I compute the ratio of inliers over the total number of keypoints in order to compute a 'distance'.

However, the distances calculated do not make the correct distinction:

```
d(img1, img2) = 0.296296
d(img1, img3) = 0.407407
d(img2, img3) = 0.362069
```

So I am unable to conclude that image 1 is different from image 2, image 1 is different from image 2 and image 2 is equal to image 3.

Is there a better method or metric to decide which images are similar?

```
Mat img_object = imread( argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
Mat img_scene = imread( argv[2], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );

//-- Step 1: Detect keypoints using SIFT
Ptr<FeatureDetector > detector;
detector = new SiftFeatureDetector();
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_object, keypoints_scene;
detector->detect( img_object, keypoints_object );
detector->detect( img_scene, keypoints_scene );

//-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
Ptr<DescriptorExtractor > extractor;
extractor = new SiftDescriptorExtractor;
Mat descriptors_object, descriptors_scene;
extractor->compute( img_object, keypoints_object, descriptors_object );
extractor->compute( img_scene, keypoints_scene, descriptors_scene );

//-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors using FLANN matcher
FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
std::vector< DMatch > matches;
matcher.match( descriptors_object, descriptors_scene, matches );

//-- Step 4: Compute homography matrix and status vector
std::vector<Point2f> obj;
std::vector<Point2f> scene;
for( int i = 0; i<matches.size(); i++){
    obj.push_back( keypoints_object[ matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
    scene.push_back( keypoints_scene[ matches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
}
std::vector<uchar> status;
Mat H = findHomography( obj, scene, status, CV_RANSAC, 3 );

//-- Step 5: Compute inliers/status.size
int inliers = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<status.size(); i++){
    inliers += status[i];
}
printf("Percentage of inliers: %f \n",( (float) inliers)/( (float) status.size() ));
```

Comment: Are you using `findHomography` correctly? Your call doesn't seem to match the API doc: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findhomography

Comment: It seems my call was incorrect, not sure why I didn't get any errors when compiling. Also changing the implementation to the one stated in the API doc didn't change any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a better method or metric to decide which images are similar?

Why don't you just find all circles and calculate distance between them?

Here's code:

```
Point2i center(vector<Point2i> contour)
{
    Moments m = moments(contour);

    return Point2i(m.m10/m.m00, m.m01/m.m00);
}


vector<Point2i> getCenters(Mat img)
{
    vector<vector<Point2i> > contours;

    threshold(img, img, 0, 255, THRESH_OTSU);

    findContours(img, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    vector<Point2i> result(contours.size());

    for (int i=0; i<contours.size(); i++)
    {
        result[i] = center(contours[i]);
    }

    return result;
}


double distanceCenter(Point2i center1, Point2i center2)
{
    return (center1.x - center2.x)*(center1.x - center2.x) + (center1.y - center2.y)*(center1.y - center2.y);
}


double distanceCenters(vector<Point2i> centers1, vector<Point2i> centers2)
{
    if (centers1.size() != centers2.size())
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        double result = 0;

        for (int i=0; i<centers1.size(); i++)
        {
            double min = INT_MAX;

            for (int j=0; j<centers2.size(); j++)
            {
                double dist = distanceCenter(centers1[i], centers2[j]);
                if (dist < min)
                {
                    min = dist;
                }
            }

            result += min;
        }

        return result;
    }
}


int main()
{
    Mat img1 = imread("image1.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE),
        img2 = imread("image2.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    cout << distanceCenters(getCenters(img1), getCenters(img2)) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And results:

> distance between 1 and 2: 14676
>
> distance between 2 and 3: 393

Comment: This worked, combined with SVD (singular value decomposition) in order to make the detected circles scale and rotation independent. Thank you.